# S3 bucket policy: In a Public Bucket, make a sub-folder private

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a bucket filled with contents that need to be mostly public. However, there is one folder (aka "prefix") that should only be accessible by an authenticated IAM user.

```
{
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AllowIAMUser",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/prefix1/prefix2/private/*",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/bobbydroptables"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "AllowAccessToAllExceptPrivate",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:GetObjectVersion"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringNotLike": {
          "s3:prefix": "prefix1/prefix2/private/"
        }
      },
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "*"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

When I try to save this policy I get the following error messages from AWS:

```
Conditions do not apply to combination of actions and resources in statement -
  Condition "s3:prefix"
  and action "s3:GetObject"
  in statement "AllowAccessToAllExceptPrivate"
```

Obviously this error applies specifically to the second statement. Is it not possible to use the "s3:prefix" condition with the "s3:GetObject" action?

Is it possible to take one portion of a public bucket and make it accessible only to authenticated users?

In case it matters, this bucket will only be accessed read-only via api.

This question is similar to [Amazon S3 bucket policy for public restrictions only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9798253/amazon-s3-bucket-policy-for-public-restrictions-only), except I am trying to solve the problem by taking a different approach.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

After much digging through AWS documentation, as well as many trial and error permutations in the policy editor, I think I have found an adequate solution.

Apparently, AWS provides an option called [NotResource](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/AccessPolicyLanguage_ElementDescriptions.html#NotResource) (not found in the Policy Generator currently).

```
The NotResource element lets you grant or deny access to all but a few
of your resources, by allowing you to specify only those resources to
which your policy should not be applied.
```

With this, I do not even need to play around with conditions. This means that the following statement will work in a bucket policy:

```
{
  "Sid": "AllowAccessToAllExceptPrivate",
  "Action": [
    "s3:GetObject",
    "s3:GetObjectVersion"
  ],
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "NotResource": [
    "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/prefix1/prefix2/private/*",
    "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/prefix1/prefix2/private"
  ],
  "Principal": {
    "AWS": [
      "*"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: It says I have to wait a day.  :)  Which I usually do anyway in case someone has a better answer.

Comment: Small correction, you're missing a comma after the `"NotResource":[...]` property to be valid JSON

Comment: In case anyone is wondering, this also works in combination with conditions. Thanks!

Comment: Works beautifully. Thank you!