# S3 storage: Make a bucket folder private

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My s3 storage settings look like this:

**Permissions > Bucket Policy**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowPublicRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

every object is public.

I have 3 folders, and would like to add a new folder which is private. How would I ensure it is private?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [S3 bucket policy: In a Public Bucket, make a sub-folder private](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20432865/s3-bucket-policy-in-a-public-bucket-make-a-sub-folder-private)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use an option called [NotResource](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/AccessPolicyLanguage_ElementDescriptions.html#NotResource).

```
The NotResource element lets you grant or deny access to all but a few
of your resources, by allowing you to specify only those resources to
which your policy should not be applied.
```

So instead of `Resource`, you should but use `NotResource`. 
With this, your 
bucket policy should be:

```
{
    "Sid": "AllowPublicReadWithPrivateFolder",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "NotResource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/your_private_folder_path/*",
    "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
        "*"
        ]
    },
    "Action": "s3:GetObject"        
}
```

[*Link to reference*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20434253/923426)