# How to restrict access of files hosted on S3 bucket to everyone

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3

We are using S3 to host our ReactJS website. The build code has all standard files that we have for a typical react application. It has an index.html, an assets folder and a JS folder.

The website is hosted all fine but I can access the contents of the my JS files and CSS that are inside the other folders.

How do I restrict this behavior? I want S3 to host my react website but only my index.html or starting page should load up. Then further navigation should be supported via React Router only. User shouldn't be able to navigate through other files.

Please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [S3 bucket policy: In a Public Bucket, make a sub-folder private](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20432865/s3-bucket-policy-in-a-public-bucket-make-a-sub-folder-private)

Comment: No @MyStackRunnethOver. It does not solve my problem. If I restrict folders like Assets and Images from public access, my index.html when loads doesn't show those images and css. I want public to cannot access it via browser URL but application should be able to access it. Please help me

Comment: I'm not sure that will work. Reason being that being able to *load* a resource, I believe, is equivalent to being able to access its URL. I'd suggest looking at the [public login page, private everything else](https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/81u3si/static_s3_website_with_login_and_private_content/) model, though it *would* require a non-public site (and I don't know if that's what you want).