# Deny Amazon S3 buckets and objects from being public

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to write bucket policies to deny public access to buckets and objects using the AWS's defense-in-depth methodology as per [How to Use Bucket Policies and Apply Defense-in-Depth to Help Secure Your Amazon S3 Data | AWS Security Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-use-bucket-policies-and-apply-defense-in-depth-to-help-secure-your-amazon-s3-data/).

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "DenyUnSecureCommunications",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::ironman111",
            "arn:aws:s3:::ironman111/*"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "Bool": {
                "aws:SecureTransport": "false"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Sid": "DenyPublicReadACL",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "*"
        },
        "Action": [
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:PutObjectAcl"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::ironman111/*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "s3:x-amz-acl": [
                    "public-read",
                    "public-read-write",
                    "authenticated-read"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Sid": "DenyPublicReadGrant",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "*"
        },
        "Action": [
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:PutObjectAcl"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::ironman111/*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringLike": {
                "s3:x-amz-grant-read": [
                    "*http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/global/AllUsers*",
                    "*http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/global/AuthenticatedUsers*"
                ]
            }
        }
    },,
    {
        "Sid": "DenyPublicListACL",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "*"
        },
        "Action": "s3:PutBucketAcl",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::ironman111",
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "s3:x-amz-acl": [
                    "public-read",
                    "public-read-write",
                    "authenticated-read"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Sid": "DenyPublicListGrant",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "*"
        },
        "Action": "s3:PutBucketAcl",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::ironman111",
        "Condition": {
            "StringLike": {
                "s3:x-amz-grant-read": [
                    "*http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/global/AllUsers*",
                    "*http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/global/AuthenticatedUsers*"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]
  }
```

However I don't see this above policy restricting me from making the bucket or object public or its ACLs public read/write.

I have later added the following to the policy. In this case, the resources are private but now I am restricted from sharing S3 buckets between accounts.

```
    {
        "Sid": "DenyAuthenticatedUsersAccess",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": [
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:PutObjectAcl"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::ironman111/*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringNotEquals": {
                "s3:x-amz-acl": "private"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Sid": "DenyAuthenticatedUsersAccess",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:PutBucketAcl",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::ironman111",
        "Condition": {
            "StringNotEquals": {
                "s3:x-amz-acl": "private"
            }
        }
    },
```

Please suggest what is wrong in the first policy.

I am unable to use IAM policy validator as it is a bucket policy. Also, I am unable to test cross-account as I do not have another canonical id.

Why does order matter in the resources array?

---

Updated:

I have added the following policy to the IAM user and it is still allowing the creation of a bucket with public access.

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Action": [
            "s3:CreateBucket",
            "s3:PutBucketAcl"
        ],
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringLike": {
                "s3:x-amz-acl": [
                    "public-read",
                    "public-read-write"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]
}
```

I need the policies to stop buckets from being public.

Comment: What do you mean by "suggest what is wrong in the first policy"? What specific problem are you encountering?

Comment: Buckets are private by default, and will only be publicly accessible if a Bucket Policy is added to the bucket. Individual objects can also be made public if the object ACL is set to public. So, what do you mean when you say "I need the policies to stop buckets from being public"? Do you mean to stop bucket policies being added in future?

Comment: Thanks for your time John. I am trying to restrict the users from making the buckets and objects from being public. I presume the best way is to restrict the users from making the changes to the policies and ACLs.

Comment: Yes, limiting those permissions to only Administrators would stop them making objects public. See also: [Amazon S3 bucket policy for public restrictions only](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9798253/174777)

Answer (score 1):

The first policy is Denying the ability to upload objects with an Access Control List that will make the objects public.

You are correct that the policy will not stop you "from making the bucket or object public or its ACLs public read/write". Rather, it is preventing files being stored as public objects in the first place.

You, as an administrator, could certainly add a Bucket Policy that then makes the whole bucket public. But that is not what the policy is trying to prevent.

Comment: I switch roles when I create a bucket. So I am not an admin while creating buckets. Don’t think the bucket ACLs are not appropriate.